# How do I test if the result from boost::bimap "right.find" was found or not?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bimap

I am new to using `boost::bimap` so forgive me if this sounds like a basic question. I am using boost 1.75.0.

Take this snippet of code:

```
if (rBiMapStudentItemDescBefore.right.count(aryStrStudentItemDesc[i]) > 0)
{
    auto it = rBiMapStudentItemDescBefore.right.find(aryStrStudentItemDesc[i]);
    CString strNewStudentItemDesc = rBiMapStudentItemDescAfter.left.find(it->second)->second;
    pEntry->SetStudentAssignmentType(static_cast<StudentAssign>(i), strNewStudentItemDesc);
}
```

It works fine. It is not clear to me from the documentation or the examples that I have found if it is possible to do away with the `right.count` call and simply test the return value of `it` like this:

```
if (it)
{

}
```

It does not like it. How do I test if the result from `right.find` was found or not? Sorry if I have missed this in the documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I still can't find actual documentation but I think I have it:

```
auto it = rBiMapStudentItemDescBefore.right.find(aryStrStudentItemDesc[i]);
if (it != rBiMapStudentItemDescBefore.right.end())
{
    CString strNewStudentItemDesc = rBiMapStudentItemDescAfter.left.find(it->second)->second;
    pEntry->SetStudentAssignmentType(static_cast<StudentAssign>(i), strNewStudentItemDesc);

}
```